# What is the best jquery plugin for tooltip like twitter message

Tags: jquery, plugins

Please anyone suggest me any jquery tooltip which can be used to display the title toolbar with ajax fetched information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit this url - http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/, here is a good jquery toolbar plugin for your purpose.